# Java - Heart Rate Calculator Help inCode

Tags: java

**This is my code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pulse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");
        String firstName = input.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter your age: ");
        int age = input.nextInt();

        Pulse person1 = new Pulse();

        System.out.printf("Calculations for %s %s age %d\n",
                person1.getFirstName(), person1.getAge());

        System.out.printf("Maximum Heart Rate: %d BPM (beats per minute)\n", person1.getMaxHeartRate());

        System.out.print("Target Heart Rate Range is: ");
        person1.displayTargetHeartRateRange();
        System.out.println();
    }

    private void displayTargetHeartRateRange() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private Object getMaxHeartRate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    private Object getAge() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    private Object getFirstName() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

**I am having problems with the getAge and all GET methods. I created a private object to fix the error message but now they aren't executing right. Someone please help me**

Comment: Can you elaborate on "aren't executing right"? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Why are all of your getters returning null? Try returning actual values.

Comment: How do I do that? I'm new to java

Comment: I'm getting after inserting my name and age : Calculations for Exception in thread "main null null age java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '&d' at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2519)

Comment: Well, you see where you've got `return null`? Don't.

Comment: This is a crazy question, what do you expect to happen? you should learn some Java before the ask this. The code generator IDE and SO are not going to solve your problems.

Comment: That is rude. I am TRYING to learn and thought others would be helpful to share their knowledge. Also, what should I return rather than null?

Comment: Read the names of the methods, maybe? What do you *think* `getAge` should return?

Comment: I would be happy to help you if I saw a little effort. I think you should start at the beginning and learn the basics of java.

Comment: You don't know my efforts though. I have been working on this code for days without figuring it out.

Comment: Seriously, you must learn the basics of java. This can be a good beginning. http://www.javaworld.com/article/2979739/learn-java/java-101-classes-and-objects-in-java.html

Answer (score -1):

```
System.out.printf( "Calculations for %s %s age %d\n", 
 person1.getFirstName(), person1.getAge() );
```

Here you call the function getFirstName and assign the return value to %s, but the return value is null because you set your value here:

```
private Object getFirstName() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

Technically that's a double error, for you also use "Object" as the return type. The compiler will deduce the right type to return, but you return a null which may cause compiler to error out.

The appropriate code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pulse
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        Pulse person1 = new Pulse();

        System.out.print( "Enter your first name: ");
        person1.firstName = input.nextLine();


        System.out.print( "Enter your age: ");
        person1.age = input.nextInt();

        System.out.printf( "Calculations for %s age %d\n", 
            person1.getFirstName(), person1.getAge() );

        System.out.printf( "Maximum Heart Rate: %d BPM (beats per minute)\n", person1.getMaxHeartRate() ); // Here, you haven't set the maxHeartRate yet, so it will be 0.

        //System.out.print( "Target Heart Rate Range is: ");
        //person1.displayTargetHeartRateRange();
        //System.out.println();

        input.close();
    }

    private int age, maxHeartRate;
    private String firstName;

    public void displayTargetHeartRateRange() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Well here you don't have anything to show because you haven't create the range of heart rate.
        // You can create an array recording all the heart rate, and sort out the highest and the lowest heart rate.
    }

    public Object getMaxHeartRate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return maxHeartRate;
    }

    public Object getAge() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return age;
    }

    public Object getFirstName() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return firstName;
    }
}
```

Run this code and you should get what you expect.

Comment: Thank you so much! All I need to do now is set the maxHeartRate?

Comment: How do I assign the max heart rate by subtracting age from 220, well more like where in my code.

Comment: public Object getMaxHeartRate() {
    maxHeartRate = 220-age;
    return maxHeartRate;
}

Comment: How about target heart rate?

Comment: You have to set it up as well. Target heart rate seems to be the realtime heart rate, and you get it using sensors normally. But, seriously, you should learn programming from the basis to get the understanding of how to think like a programmer!